# Spring - Get content as Map from spring mockMvc result

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring testing, so just wanted to know whether we can get result from mockMvc as Java Map?

```
@Test
    public void readBookmarks() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/" + userName + "/bookmarks"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(this.bookmarkList.get(0).getId().intValue())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].uri", is("http://bookmark.com/1/" + userName)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].description", is("A description")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].id", is(this.bookmarkList.get(1).getId().intValue())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].uri", is("http://bookmark.com/2/" + userName)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].description", is("A description")));
    }
```

In above example asserting each every json property of an object separately might be difficult if the object has many properties. So instead can I maintain a map(*or list `List<Map<String, Object>>`*) of expected results and assert with actual results directly?

Comment: It depends on what is being returned from your controller. This has nothing to do with mockmvc

Comment: my rest controller returns List<Map<String, Object>>. How do I convert result to this.